# What difference between _set_purecall_handler and _set_purecall_handler_m?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I debug a code, and I use **_set_purecall_handler** to set function that be called when  pure call virtual function happened. This exemple from MSDN work nice for me and do what I want: [code from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t296ys27%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
So, you can see the declaration of the function

```
    void myPurecallHandler(void)
    {
     printf("In _purecall_handler.");
     exit(0);
    }
```

this function MUST return a void value and don't have any arguments, this function is called when a pure call virtuall function happened. I have trying to overload this function to passe it a parameters (The line number where pure call virtuall function happened ), but can't success.
If you see, there is another function there: **_set_purecall_handler_m**
**What is the difference between this function and _set_purecall_handler?**

Thanks a lot,

Comment: You can't have "void values". `void` is an incomplete type, so you can never have a value of that type.

Comment: [`_set_purecall_handler_m`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t296ys27(v=vs.80).aspx) is for use with mixed mode CRT when using C++ and C++-CLI.

Comment: Kerrek SB-> Yes, this is what I meant :). Thank you

Comment: Capitain Obvlious-> Ok, Thank you. ...and i'll try to overload this also if I can :)

Comment: @Captain Why isn't that an answer to the question?

Comment: @CodyGray For some reason I always feel dirty giving a one line answer. I should though so it doesn't show up on the open list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`_set_purecall_handler_m`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t296ys27%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is for use with mixed mode CRT when using C++ and C++-CLI. If you are not working with C++-CLI you really don't need to use it. If however you are creating say a DLL that *may* be used with C++-CLi applications you might want to consider using it.